# Only one value is being written into Core Data. Why ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, core-data

I am a newbie and I would like to store and retrieve data from a `Core Data` database. 
I get all the data from a php file, which communicates with a SQL database. This php file returns a JSON object, which in turn is parsed by my app and then written into `Core Data` by doing the following:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)writeDataIntoCoreData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *articles = [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Articles" 
                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];

    for(int i= 0; i<[json count];i++){
        NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:i];

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[info objectForKey:@"userID"]];

        [articles setValue:myNumber forKey:@"articleID"];
        [articles setValue:[info objectForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"author"];
        [articles setValue:[info objectForKey:@"user_pic"] forKey:@"text"];
        NSLog(@"Name = %@",[info objectForKey:@"username"]);
        NSLog(@"Text = %@",[info objectForKey:@"user_pic"]);
    }
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

**MainViewController.m**

Here I try to retrieve **all** the data in the `Core Data` database by iterating through the `fetchedObjects`.

```
-(IBAction)showCD:(id)sender
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Articles" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"id: %@", [info valueForKey:@"articleID"]); 
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"author"]);
        NSLog(@"Text: %@", [info valueForKey:@"text"]);


    }    

}
```

The NSLog, however, only displays one object, namely the first one that was written into the database. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your

```
NSManagedObject *articles = [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Articles" 
                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

into your for loop,

```
for(int i= 0; i<[json count];i++){
    NSManagedObject *articles = [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Articles" 
                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:i];

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[info objectForKey:@"userID"]];

    [articles setValue:myNumber forKey:@"articleID"];
    [articles setValue:[info objectForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"author"];
    [articles setValue:[info objectForKey:@"user_pic"] forKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"Name = %@",[info objectForKey:@"username"]);
    NSLog(@"Text = %@",[info objectForKey:@"user_pic"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the call to `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` *inside* your loop. The way you're doing it now, you're creating just *one* managed object and then repeatedly change its attributes.